# Iphone and ipad onclick issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

onclick function on **ipad and iphone** is working fine with following code

```
<li id="321"> 
   <a class="" onclick="checkTagGroup('val');" href="javascript:void(0);" id="321"> 
           Grp 
   </a>
</li>
```

but it is not working when i include div inside li as below

```
  <li id="321"> 
<a class="" onclick="checkTagGroup(&quot;321&quot;);" href="javascript:void(0);" id="321"> 
    Grp 
</a>
    <div class="close-tag1">
       <a href="/tagsGroup/delete/TXpJeA==" id="link_id"><img src="/themes/alltimehigh/images/portlet-remove-icon.png">
       </a>
    </div>
  </li>
```

Comment: where is checkTagGroup defined? http://jsfiddle.net/6uJYp/1/ works here, with the function defined in the head

Answer (score 0):

did you tried with `onclick="checkTagGroup('321')"`

if you still have the problem please provide a jsfiddle link with more details

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to the &quot; inside the function call. Try to use the apostrophe-quote like in the first approach or use &apos; instead like this:

```
<a class="" onclick="checkTagGroup(&apos;321&apos;);" ...>
```